# Visualizador de todo tipos de documentos para vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Estoy buscando un visualizador de documentos para mi protecto de vue, desde el lado del cliente.
Probé con el de google...pero no sé porque a veces me los muestra y otras no, o si abro uno y despues otro, me muestra el anterior, no sé a que se debe, si puede ser por el tamaño o qué.
tambien he visto apryse docs, este es de pago...alguien lo conoce?
Ahora estoy usando vue2/pdf/embed, este va bien,pero solo puedo visualizar pdf, y necesitaría poder visualizar tambien .doc, .docx....
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Lamentablemente los pedidos de recomendaciones de recursos externos no están permitidos en el sitio (ni otras preguntas que generan respuestas basadas en opiniones) y lo más seguro es que esta pregunta termine cerrada por la comunidad. Si tienes un problema específico sobre el que buscas ayuda, puedes [edit] tu pregunta y pedir ayuda sobre ese tema. Un saludo.